# android .ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am working at a contacl list database application and when i click on call application is working but when i click on send email in my list i get the following error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {     act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=plain/text (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
at org.example.dbcontactconsole.Detalii.onListItemClick(Detalii.java:75)
at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My class Detalii.java:`package org.example.dbcontactconsole;

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
     import android.widget.TextView;

   public class Detalii extends ListActivity
   { 
   protected TextView contactName;
   protected TextView contactPhone;
   protected TextView email;
   protected int contactId;
   protected  List<Actiune> actiune;
   protected ActiuneAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalii);

     contactId = getIntent().getIntExtra("Contact_ID",0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DbCreate(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name,phone,email FROM contactTest1 WHERE _id=?",new    String[]{""+contactId});

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    contactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    contactName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

   actiune= new ArrayList<Actiune>();
   String phoneString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone"));
   if (phoneString!=null)
   {
    actiune.add(new Actiune("Suna la numar",phoneString,Actiune.ACTION_CALL));
    }
   String stringemail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
   if (stringemail != null) {
           actiune.add(new Actiune("Email", stringemail,Actiune.ACTION_EMAIL));
           }
   adapter = new ActiuneAdapter();
   setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
     }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Actiune action = actiune.get(position);

     Intent intent;
     switch (action.getType()) {

    case Actiune.ACTION_CALL:  
            Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + action.getData());  
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, callUri);
        startActivity(intent);
            break;

    case Actiune.ACTION_EMAIL:  
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{action.getData()});
    startActivity(intent);
    break;


     }
     }    

    class ActiuneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actiune> {

     ActiuneAdapter() {
            super(Detalii.this, R.layout.actiune_detalii, actiune);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Actiune action = actiune.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actiune_detalii, parent, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(action.getLabel());
    TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
    data.setText(action.getData());
    return view;
     }

     }

     }
```

`
And this is my MAnifest.xml :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.example.dbcontactconsole"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".DbContactConsole"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactDetails"
        android:label="@string/contact_intent"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>

         <activity android:name=".Search"
        android:label="@string/contact_in"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       </activity>
          <activity android:name=".Detalii"
        android:label="@string/contact_int"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>

   </application>
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: Do you have the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I had the same problem and restarting eclipse fixed it for me. If you are using Eclipse that is.

Comment: Are you using an emulator? If you are make sure you have installed an email client and configured it properly. By default the emulator does not have an email client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a uses-permissions android.permission.CALL_PHONE to your manifest. also possibly see:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-make-phone-call-your-application

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application

Answer (score 2):

You must add the send activity into your manifest file.